# White screen error on android studio ( If anyone can please let me know)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

The app running on my phone from the android studio shows a blank screen. It only shows a white screen when running it from the android studio on my phone as an installed app. Nothing is displayed at all, but when I run it on an android studio, there is no error. If anyone can please let me know. This is my screenshot ==>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdvNf.jpg)

.....JAVA CODE....

```
package com.example.testvegetablewheelbarrow;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

....XML CODE...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="291dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="#E60D0D"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499"
    tools:text="Hello Wold"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add screenshots to make question more relevant

Comment: Send you menifest code

Comment: Can you show us your Java/Kotlin code and layout xml-files?

Comment: I'm uploaded my code

Comment: Maybe you could try changing `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"` for `android:background="#000000".`

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because of tools:text="Hello Wold". It displays in the preview mode.

`tools:text="Hello Wold"` from namespace
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` as it is for studio editor purpose to help to edit without setting android namespace values. When developer doesn't want to set values in layout and those can be set dynamically at runtime.

try to change to

```
android:text="Hello Wold"
```

By this option, developer can avoid showing default values if he doesn't want to set. The tools would help for layout designs to view and align.